# How to Remove string after string replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For that code below the output of ins (lets assume the value of keys are summer, spring, fall, winter) is:

```
['req.body.summer, req.body.spring, req.body.fall, req.body.winter']
```

What i want is remove the string after the replace command, so i can insert it to my SQLite query. So the output must be:

```
[req.body.summer, req.body.spring, req.body.fall, req.body.winter]
```

Im just new into programming so please bear with me. Thank you!

```js
var arr = '';

Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
  arr += 'req.body.' + key + ', ';
});

var ins = [arr.replace(/,\s*$/, '')];

console.log(ins);
```

Comment: Do you want the output as an array?

Comment: Yes, No strings @SankarRaj

Comment: What is `input`? An object?

Comment: If input is an array - hence Object.keys will give "key" as indexes i.e. 0 , 1, 2 .. hence the output will be req.body.0,req.body.1 ..etc

Comment: Yes, just remove the ' in the array.. @trincot

Comment: I don't think it's possible what the type of req.body.summer would be if you remove '

Comment: This is not clear: the input is an array of strings? Like 'summer'?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Just declare `arr` as an array and Push the values into it.

```js
var arr = [];
var input = ['summer', 'spring', 'fall', 'winter'];
(input).forEach(function(key,value) {
  arr.push('req.body.' + key);
});


console.log(arr);
```

Comment: is it possible to remove the string in every element on array?

Comment: How will i remove the "" in ["req.body.spring"]? I only want [req.body.spring only]. Because in that, it will print the text req.body.spring, what i need is not string, a variable. req.body.spring will get the input value from the EJS. Im very sorry

Answer (score 1):

If the input is an array of strings, like 'summer', then do this:

```
var arr = input.map(key => req.body[key]);
```

```js
// Sample input
var input = ['summer', 'spring', 'fall', 'winter'];

// Sample req:
var req = {
    body: {
        summer: 'sun',
        spring: 'birds',
        fall: 'leaves',
        winter: 'snow'
    }
};

var arr = input.map(key => req.body[key]);

console.log(arr);
```

If you prefer the `function` syntax instead of `=>`:

```
var arr = input.map(function (key) {
    return req.body[key];
});
```

Comment: It is JavaScript. Did you try to run the snippet? Maybe you don't know the [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

Comment: Oh sorry, didnt know that, is it possible to remove the stringify of it? i only want [ sun, birds, leaves, snow ]

Comment: What is `sun` if it is not a string? A variable? If it is a variable, then it will still look up the *value* of that variable, which again could be a string. Not sure what you want. Console output *is* a string.

Comment: How will i remove the "" in ["req.body.spring"]? I only want [req.body.spring only]. Because in that, it will print the text req.body.spring, what i need is not string, a variable. req.body.spring will get the input value from the EJS. Im very sorry

Comment: Please formulate your question clearly. The quotes you see are just representation. They are not actually stored. If the value you want to get is not yet there then process the input later when the values are available.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for an Array of String Objects

```js
var arr = new Array() ;var input= { 'spring':'a','summer': 'b'}
    Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
      arr.push('req.body.' + key);
    });
    console.log(arr); // Prints ["req.body.spring", "req.body.summer"]
```

Comment: How will i remove the "" in "req.body.spring"? I only want req.body.spring only.

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez - You cannot remove the double quotes. this is a string literal - How do you want to use the Output of the program